# Writing data to external Flash Memory chip

Tags: memory, flash, nand-flash

I develop a microcontroller project that requires writing big chunks of data in a Micron 4Gb SPI NAND Flash memory and I am a little confused regarding manipulation of the Flash memory blocks.

According to the datasheet  one memory die of the specific Flash memory is organized in two planes. The Plane of even-numbered blocks and the Plane of odd-numbered blocks.

[image: Flash Memory Array Organization]

And my question is this: in order to write data continuously in the flash memory, do I have to fill with data the even-numbered blocks first(i.e. 0,2,4...2046) and then jump to odd-numbered blocks (i.e. 1,3,5,7...2047) OR is it possible for me to write data first in block 0 then in block 1 then in block 2, etc?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the numbering was created to screw over the naive guy writing purely sequentially (0,1,2,3,4,5,...).

Comment: so your suggestion is...

Comment: The suggestion would be to investigate every bit of documentation and AppNotes from the part manufacturer. If the answer is not forthcoming from that material then it may be necessary to contact the company's support folks to have them help to explain.

Comment: App Notes and datasheet don't mention something on this. So I assume that I am not limited to write first to the even and then the odd blocks. I will try to write data in blocks  sequentially block_0 block_1 2 3 ... and see what happens.